# Object of Wrong GDALDatasetShadow Error

Tags: gdal

I am trying to crop the TIF images based on the shape file. After searching the web, I found the following code and manipulated it.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import os

input_path = '/.../pics'
output_path = '/.../clipped_pics/'

bandList = [band for band in os.listdir(input_path) if band[-4:]=='.tif']
shp_clip = '/.../Index.shp'

for band in bandList:
    print(output_path + band[:-4]+'_c2'+band[-4:])
    options = gdal.WarpOptions(cutlineDSName=shp_clip,cropToCutline=True)
    outBand = gdal.Warp(srcDSOrSrcDSTab=input_path + band,
                        destNameOrDestDS=output_path + band[:-4]+'_c2'+band[-4:],
                        options=options)
    outBand= None
```

However, this is the error I get:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-e2d9d6412405> in <module>
      4     outBand = gdal.Warp(srcDSOrSrcDSTab=input_path + band,
      5                         destNameOrDestDS=output_path + band[:-4]+'_c2'+band[-4:],
----> 6                         options=options)
      7     outBand= None

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py in Warp(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSOrSrcDSTab, **kwargs)
    673 
    674     if _is_str_or_unicode(destNameOrDestDS):
--> 675         return wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSTab, opts, callback, callback_data)
    676     else:
    677         return wrapper_GDALWarpDestDS(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSTab, opts, callback, callback_data)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py in wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(*args)
   4315 def wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(*args):
   4316     """wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(char const * dest, int object_list_count, GDALWarpAppOptions warpAppOptions, GDALProgressFunc callback=0, void * callback_data=None) -> Dataset"""
-> 4317     return _gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(*args)
   4318 class GDALVectorTranslateOptions(_object):
   4319     """Proxy of C++ GDALVectorTranslateOptions class."""

TypeError: object of wrong GDALDatasetShadow
```

Comment: The only thing that I can see is that srcDSOrSrcDSTab=input_path + band doesn't have a separator, consider using os.path.join instead of simple concatenation: srcDSOrSrcDSTab=os.path.join(input_path, band) and destNameOrDestDS=os.path.join(output_path, band[:-4]+'_c2'+band[-4:]) which ensures the correct os.sepchar is used to join the path name. You also may want to consider os.path.splitext(band)[1].lower() to break your filename, [-4:] doesn't always work if your raster is .jpeg for example.

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael! It works now.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, do you happen to have an idea about this question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370564/problem-with-the-edges-when-clipping-raster

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I got the same error because I tried to pass in a pathlib Path object rather than a string.